# mod_rewrite to transform old request urll into new one

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

.hello - i need to transform old url requests to fit into the new sites content;

ie 'art-consultancy' used to be 'consultancy' so how can i grab 'consultancy' urls and transform them into 'art-consultancy'

MY RULE if ^consultancy$ MAKE ^art-consultancy$ and continue to the rules below...

```
RewriteRule ^art-consultancy$ consultancy-02.php [L]
RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/$ consultancy-02.php [L]

RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ consultancy-02.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ consultancy-02.php?section=$1 [L]
#
RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ article-01.php [L]
RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ article-01.php [L]
```

any help appreciated!

ps. tried Redirect /consultancy /art-consultancy without any luck. Think this method needs an actual file?

best, Dc

Comment: What is your question? Does your rule not work?

Comment: how can i get the htaccess to change 'consultancy' to 'art-consultancy' before the rest of the rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just have to do exactly what you said you wanted to do, in a similar way that you've done with the other rules, so I'm not sure how much this qualifies in the way of an "answer"...But, for the sake of completeness, I'll go ahead and write up the full thing:

(Also, I condensed your other rules into single lines)

```
# Add in this condition because consultancy-02.php matches here too
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^consultancy(.*)$ art-consultancy$1

RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/?$ consultancy-02.php [L]
RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ consultancy-02.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^art-consultancy/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ article-01.php [L]
```

If you wanted `consultancy` to be transformed to `art-consultancy` in the user's browser URL, you should replace the first `RewriteRule` with this:

```
RewriteRule ^consultancy(.*)$ /art-consultancy$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not entirely sure why the `Redirect` didn't work like you expected it to though. If you look at your server's `error_log` it might tell you, but otherwise it's hard to speculate without knowing what your site's directory structure looks like.

Comment: this is perfect!

RewriteRule ^consultancy(.*)$ /art-consultancy$1 [R=301,L]

many thanks! Dan.